# Kendo UI Sparkline - Datasource/Series/Categories

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo UI Sparkline now that I am populating from my model with the following:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Sparkline()
    .Name("jph-graph")
    .Theme("black")
    .Type(SparklineType.Column)
    .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip.Format("{0:n2}"))
    .Data(Model.jphList.Select(g => g.value).ToList())
)
```

The Sparkline populates properly with that.

I want to add a category so that I can include that value in my ToolTip.  All I could find were references to using the category, so I started trying to use .DataSource so I could implement that.  Now I can't even get the Sparkline to populate with the defined Datasource and Series, much less get the Category working.  Here is the code that I have that does NOT populate the Sparkline.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Sparkline()
    .Name("jph-graph")
    .Theme("black")
    .Type(SparklineType.Column)
    .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip.Format("{0:n2}"))
    .DataSource(ds => Model.jphList.Select(g => new { date = g.production_date, value = g.value }).ToList())
    .Series(series => series.Column("value"))
)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Never fails, you look at and Google something for hours and then moments after posting the question you see your own stupid mistake...

```
@(Html.Kendo().Sparkline(Model.jphList)
    .Name("jph-graph")
    .Theme("black")
    .Type(SparklineType.Column)
    .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip.Format("{0:n2}"))
    .DataSource(ds => Model.jphList.Select(g => new { date = g.production_date, value = g.value }).ToList())
    .Series(series => series.Column("value"))
)
```